# Is there a way to connect an interactive Slack Bot from the Slack API to Outlook API?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, slack

I am trying to build a Slack bot to interact with the corporate Outlook account for users. I want events posted in users' slack channels to be automatically updated into the user's Outlook email and/or calendar for automated reminders and scheduling. I'm wondering how I would go about enabling the Slack bot to interact with with Microsoft Outlook's API, if possible?

I'm starting with the publicly available slackapi/python-slackclient available on github. I've read that compatibility for this exists in Office 365, but I'm wondering if it is possible in the more traditional versions of the office suite.

Comment: what do you mean by "traditional versions of office suite"? Like an in-house office server installation?

Comment: yes, the office suite installed on your desktop as opposed to office 365

Comment: Ok. That means you are looking to interface a Slack app with an exchange server (which is where the outlook mailboxes are stored). I would research what APIs are available for the version of exchange server your company is running.

Comment: A Slack app is just an ordinary web app. It can in theory interface with anything as long as it is reachable from the public Internet.

Comment: I see!!! 
So I found:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations 
and 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/start-using-web-services-in-exchange
I can check what exchange server version is being used for the active directory.
Now, if I cannot find a way to connect the Slack app to the exchange server, would it feasible to listen for system calls on the local machine to the exchange server instead?

Comment: So unfortunately it looks like there are already existing slack applications that do this for outlook and other platforms as well, my mistake. I guess a better question is: What would be a novel use case for integrating a Slack app with a corporate exchange server?